# MySQL insert if data doesn't exist(excluding primary key)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a sql insert only if the data doesn't already exist in the table. I have a language table that has a auto incremented primary id field and a string description field to capture the name of the language(ex. English). I want to be able to insert into the database only if the description field is not already there. The primary id doesn't matter. So I only want to insert into the table if "English" isn't already a value in the table. Also, I am only given the description to check if it's already in the database (I mention this because the ON DUPLICATE KEY requires all fields to be matching and I don't have the id).

I have searched and tried so many queries without any of them producing the correct results. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why can't you just create a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `description` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply add a UNIQUE constraint to the description field.

and then use "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in your code. Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you need to update rows that have UNIQUE key conflict - you should use "meda" answer.
if you need only insert rows without duplicates you should also add UNIQUE constraint but with using query:

INSERT IGNORE INTO table SET ....

this query will insert row that have no conflict and ignore others without any mysql errors